# Display SSRS Report Author

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS there is a report property called `Author`.

[image: pointing out report]

I am attempting to display the author at the bottom of my report in a text box. I tried the following:

```
="Report Created By " & Globals!Author
```

But it didn't work. Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: I'm not sure if this property is exposed. I've not checked but maybe there is a way you could query the reportserver.dbo.catalog table and see if it's in there (although I doubt it). I think the description is available in the catalog so maybe you could use that instead but it would reply on the report being deployed before you could test.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this data is exposed in th report builder, however, If you want to maintain a custom assembly and embed it in your report then you can take the code below and add to be called by your report's custom code.

1. Create class library project that references Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010 similar to below.

   ```
   using RS = Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010;

   public class MicrosoftReportingService //: IReportService
   {
        private RS.ReportingService2010 _service=new RS.ReportingService2010();

        public void CheckConnection()
        {
            _service.Url = <SSSR_ENPOINT>;
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(<USER_NAME>,<PASSWORD>,<DOMAIN>);
            _service.Credentials=credentials;           
         }

        private List<RS.CatalogItem> GetReportsInFolder(string path)
       {
           CheckConnection();
           RS.CatalogItem[] reportItems = _service.ListChildren(path, true);
           List<RS.CatalogItem> result = new List<RS.CatalogItem>();
           foreach (RS.CatalogItem reportItem in reportItems)
               if (reportItem.TypeName == "Report" || reportItem.TypeName == "LinkedReport")
                   result.Add(reportItem);
           return result;
       }

       public CatalogItem GetReportData(string reportPath, string reportName)
       {
           List<RS.CatalogItem> reportItems = GetReportsInFolder(reportPath);
           return reportItems.Where(p=>p.Name==reportName).FirstOrDefault();
       }

       public string GetReportAuthor(string reportPath, string reportName)
       {
           CatalogItem item = GetReportData(reportPath,reportName);
           return (item == null) ? "" : item.CreatedBy;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Include the assembly in your report.
3. Once the assembly is on the report server and referenced by your report then you can create a wrapper function in the report custom code similar to:

   ```
   Public GetReportAuthor(reportPath As String, reportName As String) As String
       Dim rs As New MicrosoftReportingService()
       Return rs.GetReporAuthor(reportPath, reportName)
   End Procedure
   ```
4. Finally, you can embed the code into an expression.

   ```
    lblAuthor = Code.GetReportAuthor(<REPORT_PATH>,<REPORT_NAME>)
   ```